# I have these models i want to get the postinlanguage queryset based on how much comments they have

Tags: python, django, database

i have these models in django

```
class PostInLanguages(models.Model):
    post_in_language_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, related_name='post_language', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Languages, default=2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_post_language = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent_post_language_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
        'User', through='PostLanguageLike', related_name='post_like', blank=True)
    hash_tag = models.ManyToManyField('HashtagName', through='Hashtag', related_name='hash_tag', blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.post.id)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
                models.Index(fields=['post_in_language_uuid', 'parent_post_language_id', 'is_post_language']),
            ]
```

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    language_post = models.ForeignKey(
        PostInLanguages, null=False, related_name='comment_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Languages, default=2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_post_comment = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent_post_comment_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]
        indexes = [
                models.Index(fields=['comment_uuid', 'parent_post_comment_id', 'is_post_comment', 'language_post']),
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.user)

    def total_comment(self):
        return self.language_post.count()
```

Im trying to get the postinlanguage queryset based on how much comments they have.

and i want to make the filter of minimum this much comments

haven't got any success.

Comment: `PIL.objects.annotate(c=Count("comment_data")).filter(c__gte=min_comments)`

Comment: Thanks bro ill Try this in morning let see
Actually im very noob in django orm filter queries can u suggest me any book or documentation so i can start practicing on it